# Blocktrail payments API, How to get the values that adress receive

Tags: php, payment, blockchain

I'am tryng to get the value that an adress sent me on my adress, I have already setted up the webhook, but i can't understand a thing...
I have this array->

```
Array
(
    [network] => tBTC
    [event_type] => address-transactions
    [addresses] => Array
        (
            [2MyXzRYSzrExLitY6FumGC3QgzCeqVoeQC1] => -49320
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [raw] => 
            [hash] => 
            [first_seen_at] => 2017-10-13T17:19:35+0000
            [last_seen_at] => 2017-10-13T17:19:35+0000
            [block_height] => 1210150
            [block_time] => 2017-10-13T17:20:18+0000
            [block_hash] => 
            [confirmations] => 2
            [is_coinbase] => 
            [estimated_value] => 30000
            [total_input_value] => 49320
            [total_output_value] => 45510
            [total_fee] => 3810
            [estimated_change] => 15510
            [estimated_change_address] => 2N7iSxafSoio4RE8wrd6outJNmbMkyP9QuL
            [high_priority] => 
            [enough_fee] => 
            [contains_dust] => 
            [inputs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [index] => 0
                            [output_hash] => 
                            [output_index] => 0
                            [output_confirmed] => 1
                            [value] => 49320
                            [sequence] => 4294967295
                            [address] => 2MyXzRYSzrExLitY6FumGC3QgzCeqVoeQC1
                            [type] => scripthash
                            [multisig] => 
                            [multisig_addresses] => 
                            [script_signature] => 
                        )

                )

            [outputs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [index] => 0
                            [value] => 30000
                            [address] => 2NBkQ8aTq8yeXdMWtxXNuxNgEHYnrzvcpV2
                            [type] => scripthash
                            [multisig] => 
                            [multisig_addresses] => 
                            [script] => OP_HASH160 OP_EQUAL
                            [script_hex] => 
                            [spent_hash] => 
                            [spent_index] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [index] => 1
                            [value] => 15510
                            [address] => 2N7iSxafSoio4RE8wrd6outJNmbMkyP9QuL
                            [type] => scripthash
                            [multisig] => 
                            [multisig_addresses] => 
                            [script] => OP_HASH160 OP_EQUAL
                            [script_hex] => 
                            [spent_hash] => 
                            [spent_index] => 0
                        )

                )

            [opt_in_rbf] => 
            [unconfirmed_inputs] => 
            [lock_time_timestamp] => 
            [lock_time_block_height] => 
            [size] => 367
        )

    [retry_count] => 0
```

And I'am tryng to get ONLY THE VALUE OF BTC (SATOSHI) THAT COME ON MY ADRESS, SO WITH THE SUBSTRACTION OF THE FEES, i thought that for get this values I had to get the

```
$Data=BlocktrailSDK::getWebhookPayload();
$Data['data']['estimated_value'];
```

Is this correct way to get  at the 1000000%  THE VALUE OF BTC (SATOSHI) THAT COME ON MY ADRESS, SO WITH THE SUBSTRACTION OF THE FEES, if is not what is the correct way??Anyway thanks for ready, hope that you all had a good day, and thanks for your time :)

P.S Note that on this transaction i sent 30000 satoshi+fees!

Comment: A little less random CAPITALIZED WORDS would be nice.

Comment: did you get the answer? I have the same problem.